# C++ MySQL Fetch Row

Tags: c++, sql, mysql

I have this little code, I am trying to connect to a database, which works fine, now I want to select/create a table, which is also fine, but I cannot for whatever reason select a specific row. I do not want to loop over everything, I just want to select e.g. row 6 of the column `id`.

```
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/*
Include directly the different
headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
MySQL Connector/C++ Complete Example 2
37
(and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("server_database");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE testit(id INT, label CHAR(1))");
        stmt->execute("INSERT INTO testit(id, label) VALUES (1, 'a')");
        stmt->execute("INSERT INTO testit(id, label) VALUES (2, 'b')");
        stmt->execute("INSERT INTO testit(id, label) VALUES (3, 'c')");
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id, label FROM testit ORDER BY id ASC");
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    int aasd;
    std::cin >> aasd;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to know, how I can select specific rows, print them out or do something with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to select the row : n

```
SELECT id FROM testit LIMIT 1 OFFSET n-1;
```

in C++ :

```
 int n=6;

 // build the string query
 std::ostringstream oss;
 oss << "SELECT id FROM testit LIMIT 1 OFFSET " << n-1;
 std::string query = oss.str();

 res = stmt->executeQuery(query);
 cout << "id = '" << res->getInt(1) << "'" << endl;
```

don't forget to :

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: that doesnt work, even if i type it into mysql directly
i did it like this to select row 0 :
`SELECT id FROM testit LIMIT 1 OFFSET (1-1);`

Comment: Got it with :
`SELECT id FROM testit LIMIT 2,1`
Now, how do i print this row with c++ ?

Comment: remove the parentheses

Comment: use `res->getInt()` for INT col and `getString()` for string col

Comment: can you clarify what is the  output table that you want??

Comment: This solution doesnt work, because n i not defined and youre doing math in a string, which is not supported
For some reason this doesnt work also :
`cout << ", id = '" << res->getInt("id") << "'" << endl;`